# How to display query result in new line

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like the following

```
Item Name | Date       | Previous Data | Updated Data
Unit 1    | 1-Jul-2013 | 500           | 550 
Unit 1    | 1-Aug-2013 | 550           | 550
Unit 1    | 1-Sep-2013 | 450           | 600 
Unit 1    | 1-Oct-2013 | 600            | 550
```

I want them to be displayed by using query as the following

```
Title     | Jul | Aug   | Sep | Oct
Prev. Data| 500 | 550   | 450 | 600
Upd. Data | 550 | 550   | 600 | 550
```

I used `UNION` before to make sure the table are according to what I want, but I am wondering if there is an easier way to do it.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: I think you're looking for the pivot function.

Comment: You have to use SQL PIVOT... 
Check this out...
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to convert the 2 columns `[Previous Data]` and `[Updated Date]` to rows and then you can use `PIVOT` on `Date` column

```
Select col,
[1] as Jan,
[2] Feb,
[3] Mar,
[4] Apr,
[5] May,
[6] Jun,
[7] Jul,
[8] Aug,
[9] Sep,
[10] Oct,
[11] Nov,
[12] Dec
from 
(
  select month(Date) as TMonth, col, value
  from Table1
  cross apply
  (
    select 'Previous Data', [Previous Data]
    union all
    select 'Updated Date', [Updated Data]
  ) c(col, value)
)a
PIVOT
(
 Sum(value)
 for Tmonth in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
)pvt
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8cb29/10)

Comment: Thanks Praveen. But now I wanted to add another column to the far right, where it will calculate the average for each quarter. For Q1, it will calculate the average from Jan to Mac, Q2 from Apr to Jun, and so on. Would you have any idea on how do I achieve that?

Comment: Just create a computer column like `isnull([1],0)+isnull([2],0)+isnull([3],0)
       +isnull([4],0))/4 as Q1`

Answer (score 0):

Pls try this........

```
select 'PreviousData' as Title,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct from
(
select a.itemname,left(datename(mm,convert(date,a.date)),3) [date]
 ,a.previousdata from @tab a
 ) srs
 pivot
 (
 sum(previousdata) for [date] in (jul,aug,sep,oct)
 ) pt
union all
 select 'UpdatedData' as Title,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct from
(
select a.itemname,left(datename(mm,convert(date,a.date)),3) [date]
 ,a.Updateddata from @tab a
 ) srs
 pivot
 (
 sum(Updateddata) for [date] in (jul,aug,sep,oct)
 ) pt
```